# I can't get a user's status with my Discord bot. Solutions?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to have a bot routinely check on a specific user's status. How do I get that user's status?

I haven't been able to get this working at all, either getting an error message, or undefined.

Method 1:

```js
var test = new Discord.User("*userid*");

function findStatus() {
  var status = test.user;
  console.log(test);
  console.log(status);
}
```

Method 2:

```js
var status = "*userid*".presence.status;
```

What I expect is a string ("online", "idle", "offline") saying what the user's status is.

Result 1:
User {}
undefined

Result 2:
Cannot read property 'status' of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems:**

Your first method doesn't work because you're attempting to construct a new [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object yourself. Your usage of the constructor is actually incorrect, but it's not going to have any valid data anyway. The constructor is only meant to be used internally. `User.user` is also not a valid property of a User.

Your second method doesn't work because you're trying to read nonexistent properties of a string.

**Solution:**

0. Create your Discord Client through the [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) constructor.
1. To retrieve a User from Discord, use the [`Client.fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser) method.
2. To check their status, use [`User.presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=presence) and [`Presence.status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status).

```js
client.fetchUser('someID')
  .then(user => {
    if (!user) return console.error('Unable to find user.');

    const status = user.presence.status;

    console.log(`${user.tag}'s status is ${status.toUpperCase()}.`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```